# changing a variable using gets.chomp()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gets, chomp

im trying to write to a file using this code:

```
  puts "-------------------- TEXT-EDITOR --------------------"
def tor(old_text)
  old_text = gets.chomp #
end


$epic=""

def torr(input)

  tore=  $epic += input + ", "

File.open("tor.txt", "w") do |write|
  write.puts tore
  end
end



loop do
  output = tor(output)
  torr(output)
end
```

i have read the ultimate guide to ruby programming 
and it says if i want to make a new line using in the file im writing to using `File.open` 
i must use `"line one", "line two` 
how can i make this happend using gets.chomp()? try my code and you will see what i mean
thank you.

Comment: What is your code supposed to do? It would also help if your methods had more meaningful names

Comment: my code is supposed to make a new file and when you type something it would make a new line for each time you press enter / make a new sentence. for example when you do                     `File.open("tor.txt", "w") do |write|
  write.puts "line one", "line two"
  end
end`         it makes a new line i wanna know how i can do this with gets.chomp() it doesent make a new line :( no matter what i type in my gets.chomp()   do you understand what i mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `gets` method will bring in any amount of text but it will terminate when you hit 'Enter' (or once the `STDIN` receives `\n`). This input record separator is stored in the global variable `$/`. If you change the input separator in your script, the `gets` method will actually trade the 'Enter' key for whatever you changed the global variable to.

```
$/ = 'EOF' # Or any other string
lines = gets.chomp
> This is
> multilined
> textEOF
lines #=> 'This is\nmultilined\ntext'
```

Enter whatever you want and then type 'EOF' at the end. Once it 'sees' EOF, it'll terminate the `gets` method. The `chomp` method will actually strip off the string 'EOF' from the end.

Then write this to your text file and the `\n` will translate into new lines.

```
File.open('newlines.txt', 'w') {|f| f.puts lines}
```

newlines.txt:

> This is
>   multilined
>   text

Answer (score 0):

If you dont use .chomp() the \n character will be added whenever you write a new line, if you save this to the file it also will have a new line. .chomp() removes those escape characters from the end of the input.

If this doesnt answer your question, i am sorry i dont understand it.